# Error while doing npm install for my node project

Tags: node.js, npm

```
D:\gegdc\AS332703\predix-seed-develop>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\gegdc\\AS332703\\Software\\Nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\gegdc\\AS
332703\\Software\\Nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDepend
encies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-requirejs@0.4.4 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-bump@0.8.0 wants grunt@>=1.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.8.3 wants grunt@0.4.x
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-autoprefixer@3.0.4 wants grunt@>=0.4.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.8.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-config@0.2.2 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@0.8.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-connect@0.7.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer load-grunt-tasks@3.5.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.12.3 wants grunt@>=0.4.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\gegdc\AS332703\predix-seed-develop\npm-debug.log
```

I am getting this error: `npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!`

I tried updating the node installation, I also tried updating the node dependency version, and still get the same issue.

Comment: The error is not in npm, but in your configuration, could you post the content of `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The error **npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!** indicates a library dependency for the project as specified in the `package.json` is incompatible with the version of another.  In this case I believe that grunt-bump@0.8.0 requires a newer version of grunt but that you may be able to safely downgrade to 0.7.0 as discussed in the Predix [forums](http://forum.predix.io/questions/8524/cannot-install-predix-seed-it-was-working-fine-las.html).

Somebody else ran into this and submitted an [issue](https://github.com/PredixDev/predix-seed/issues/45) in the github project repos to address the [predix-seed](https://github.com/PredixDev/predix-seed) source directly.

Comment: yes i downgraded with grunt-bump to 0.7.0 and it worked smoothly. thanks :)